# Does this non-negative non-increasing function eventually attain $0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability

> Let $\phi(z): \mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,B]$, with $B>0$,  be a non-negative and non-increasing  function such that $\phi(0) = B$ and
>   \begin{align}
> \phi(z) = \max(0, E[\phi(z+X)]+a\mu - c),
> \end{align}
>   where $X$ is a random variable with mean $E[X]=\mu>0$ such that $c - a\mu=\epsilon > 0$ and finite second moment.
>
> *Show that $\phi(z_0) = 0$ for some sufficiently large $z_0$.*

I came across this argument in a paper by Thomas Ferguson about optimal stopping rules [1]:

*Suppose $\phi(z)>0$ for any $z$, then $E[\phi(z+X)] > c - a\mu = \epsilon > 0$, which since $\phi$ is non-increasing implies $\phi(z)>\epsilon$, which in turn implies that $E[\phi(z+X)]>2\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $z$, etc. Eventually this would imply that $E[\phi(z+X)]>B$, a contradiction.*

However, it is not clear to me, how one can infer that $E[\phi(z+X)]> \epsilon$ implies $\phi(z)>\epsilon$ when there are no additional constraints on $X$ such as boundedness.

[1] Thomas S. Ferguson, "Some Time-invariant Stopping Rule Problems".

Comment: Since the second moment is finite, if $\phi(z_1)\leq\epsilon_1<\epsilon$ then I think there will be some $z>z_1$ such that $P(z+X<z_1)$ is as small as we need in order to guarantee that $E[\phi(z+X)]\leq\epsilon_1+P(z+X<z_1)B<\epsilon.$

Comment: But $X$ is only in the argument of $\phi$.